# Do anyone have a working example of gevent-socketio?

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, gevent

All the forks of gevent-socketio in bitbucket and github have examples/chat.py that do not work.
Can anyone find me a working example of gevent-socketio?

Comment: What fails?

Did you install the required libraries? `easy_install gevent gevent-socketio`

Comment: Nothing fails. All the libraries are installed successfully.
`python chat.py` also runs. But in browser, after you type nickname and hit 'enter', the chat window doesn't appear. Instead the nickname input 'behaves' as if it didn't submit the form. And in some forks of gevent-socketio, msg appears only in self's chat window and not in other users'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the new official repository at:

- https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio

and take a look at the example apps in there, most should be up to date now (I think there was a commit with some fixes to the chat.py example recently)

- https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/tree/master/examples

Take a look at the docs also:

- http://readthedocs.org/docs/gevent-socketio/en/latest/

Comment: It worked after applying this patch https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/pull/25 as referenced in https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/issues/12#issue-ref-13709053.

Comment: I also found that the chat example didn't work, but that was because I had old versions of gevent / greenlet / libevent installed. In the future, include the error message you get; I was getting KeyError on environ['socketio'].

Comment: chat.py in github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio is finally working.

Answer (score 1):

I make on websockets.
This is draft code but it work.

```
import os
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
import geventwebsocket

class eServer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        path = os.path.dirname(geventwebsocket.__file__)
        agent = "gevent-websocket/%s" % (geventwebsocket.__version__)
        print "Running %s from %s" % (agent, path)
        self.all_socks = []
        self.s = WSGIServer(("", 8000), self.echo, handler_class=geventwebsocket.WebSocketHandler)
        self.broken_socks = []
        self.s.serve_forever()

    def echo(self, environ, start_response):
        websocket = environ.get("wsgi.websocket")
        if websocket is None:
            return http_handler(environ, start_response)
        try:
            while True:
                message = websocket.receive()
                if message is None:
                    break
                self.sock_track(websocket)
                for s in self.all_socks:
                    try:
                        s.send(message)
                    except Exception:
                        print "broken sock"
                        self.broken_socks.append(s)
                        continue
                if self.broken_socks:
                     for s in self.broken_socks:
                         print 'try close socket'
                         s.close()
                        if s in self.all_socks:
                            print 'try remove socket'
                            self.all_socks.remove(s)
                    self.broken_sock = []
                    print self.broken_sock
            websocket.close()
        except geventwebsocket.WebSocketError, ex:
            print "%s: %s" % (ex.__class__.__name__, ex)


    def http_handler(self, environ, start_response):
        if environ["PATH_INFO"].strip("/") == "version":
            start_response("200 OK", [])
            return [agent]
        else:
            start_response("400 Bad Request", [])
            return ["WebSocket connection is expected here."]

    def sock_track(self, s):
        if s not in self.all_socks:
            self.all_socks.append(s)
            print self.all_socks



s = eServer()
```

and client's html like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000");
    socket.onopen = function(){
        console.log('socket open');
}
    socket.onmessage = function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
        $('#recive').after('<p>'+msg.data+'</p>');
}
    $('#send-btn').click(function(){
        var txt = $('#txt').val();
        console.log(txt);
        socket.send(txt);
    })

});

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
    <input type="button" id="send-btn" value="Send"></input>
    <div id="recive"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But websockets are not supported by all browsers. So I want to use socket.io which supports different transport mechanisms.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I don't try it with socket.io, but websockets work in all modern browsers.

Comment: suzanshakya the IE. ui is buggy underlying socket.io code is fixed by me you have to grab the latest copy from github

Answer (score 1):

what browser do you use. I saw this behavior with IE. both Mozilla and chrome were fine. there were issues with the flashscket protocol which I have fixed so ie should work but the jquery UI does not work that is the issue. don't know enough JS to fix it

Comment: I used Opera, Mozilla, Chrome and Safari.